# C# Regex is matching too much

Tags: c#, regex, multiple-matches

My regex should work like this: https://regex101.com/r/dY9jI4/1
It should Match only Nicknames (`personaname`).

My C# code looks like this:

```
string pattern = @"personaname"":\s+""([^""]+)""";
string users = webClient.DownloadString("http://pastebin.com/raw/cDHTXXD3");
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(users);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

But in VS15 my regex in matching my whole pattern, so console output looks like:

```
personaname": "Tom"
personaname": "Emily"
```

Is something wrong with my pattern? How can I fix it?

Comment: Use a json parser like [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) `var names = JObject.Parse(users)["response"]["players"].Select(x => (string)x["personaname"]).ToList();`

Comment: Thanks for advice. I wanted regex way, but this is also useful. I will try it in next opportunity :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So while the actual answer would be to just parse this JSON and get the data, your problem is in Match, you need `match.Groups[1].Value` to get that unnamed group.

```
string pattern = @"personaname"":\s+""(?<name>[^""]+)""";
string users = webClient.DownloadString("http://pastebin.com/raw/cDHTXXD3");
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(users);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["name"].Value);
}
```

Comment: match.Groups[1].Value would work too -- though both your suggestions are better.

Comment: Yes, I know I can parse it and get these nicknames. But the problem is I was never working with JSON and Regex. I decided for regex because I was thinking it will be easier for me. But now I see Regex way was not so easy like i thought. Your code works of course. Big thanks for help!

Comment: Gahhh! It's not zero, it's 1 -- 0 is the whole match. I fixed my bonehead comment.

Comment: haha, fixed my answer as well :) @Chamov dont forget to mark/upvote and welcome to stackexchange :)

Comment: With "1" works also. // Yes, Im upvoting of course :)

Comment: Who dv'd this?!